# How to iterate a function inside a list in which you want to separate the different items

Tags: python, numpy

In the next code I download a file from a URL, open the file, and I have rows and columns of data. What I want to do is to create a loop (or something like that) to individualize all the items.

Data downloaded:

```
['amount,duration,rate,down_payment\n', '100000,36,0.08,20000\n', '200000,12,0.1,\n', '628400,120,0.12,100000\n', '4637400,240,0.06,\n', '42900,90,0.07,8900\n', '916000,16,0.13,\n', '45230,48,0.08,4300\n', '991360,99,0.08,\n', '423000,27,0.09,47200']
```

The code:

```
import os
import urllib.request

url1 = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aakashns/257f6e6c8719c17d0e498ea287d1a386/raw/7def9ef4234ddf0bc82f855ad67dac8b971852ef/loans1.txt'

os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True) #Create a folder called 'data'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url1,'./data/datos1.txt')

with open ('./data/datos1.txt') as file1:
    file1_lines=file1.readlines()

    print("OUR DATA\n")

    print(file1_lines)

#------INDIVIDUALIZED HEADER-----

    print("\nIndividualized header:\n")

    def titles(header_title):
        return header_title.strip().split(',')

    headers=titles(file1_lines[0])
    print(headers)

#------INDIVIDUALIZED VALUES-----

    print("\nindividualized values from file1:\n")

    def parse_values(data1):
        values=[]
        for i in data1.strip().split(','):
            if i =='':
                values.append(0.0)
            else:
                try:
                    values.append(float(i))
                except ValueError:
                    values.append(i)
        return values


        for item in (1,2,3):

            new_data=parse_values(file1_lines[item])
            print(new_data)
```

I tried to make a loop which works with all the data at once (except headers), but it separates everything by characters, like `[1234,678]--> [1,2,3,4,6,7,8]`

So I thought to create a final loop that repeats the `parse_values` function, but it does not work, maybe because between the brackets in the `file1_lines[]` it has to be a number. But I don´t know what else can I do.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "individualize values". What do you want the data to look like exactly? What do you want to do with it in the end? When you say "it does not work" what specifically goes wrong? Error message? Bad output? Be specific.

Comment: The result I was expecting is [100000,36,0.08,20000] for every different line os data. An when I said it does not work what I mean is that nothing happens, no errors but no results. Thank you

Comment: Are you just trying to split and flatten the lists? Maybe `[item for s in myList for item in s.strip().split(',')]` would be a good place to start.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I want to every line of data be in a different list, like headers in one list, first line of data in another list, etc.

Comment: I posted what I think you want. If this does, please accept answer, if not let me know.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what exactly your code is doing wrong, though it seems over complicated for this task.

The below code should accomplish what you want.

```py
import os
import urllib.request

url1 = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aakashns/257f6e6c8719c17d0e498ea287d1a386/raw/7def9ef4234ddf0bc82f855ad67dac8b971852ef/loans1.txt'

os.makedirs('./data', exist_ok=True) #Create a folder called 'data'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url1,'./data/datos1.txt')

output = []

with open ('./data/datos1.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1.readlines():
        entry = line.strip().split(',')
        output.append(entry);
        
        #convert entry values to floats if possible
        for i in range(0, len(entry)):
            try:
                entry[i] = float(entry[i])
            except:
                pass
```

We're just looping through the lines of the file, creating an `entry` which is just the line split by ',' and finally we try to convert each string value in the entry to a float if possible.

It's very odd to keep the header row at the top of what appears to be a data array. Usually a data array is just pure data of one type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. But you didn´t take into account that if in any position there is no data, it should add a 0.0 so all the arrays have the same lenght.  That should be added in the first or in the second for loop?                      
                                                                                                                                               PD: I am taking a course and i was following the instructions so maybe my code was a like messy because it tries to taught a lot of things I guess.